# Java - regex parsing x occurrence of match

Tags: java, regex, string, parsing

I would like to parse this string:

```
{HHH { AAAA } fS } SFS}
```

to get output by parenthesis number. If i want to get first the output should be :

```
HHH { AAAA
```

when second :

```
HHH { AAAA } fS
```

etc.

I tried this regex but it didn't give me expected results :

```
\{(.*?)\}{1}
```

Comment: It's not something you can easily do with regex. You need to parse your string and find matching brackets. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/546433/regular-expression-to-match-outer-brackets

Comment: And what makes you think you want to use regex?

Comment: I just wanted to ask if it is possible with regex. What a shame it isnt. ahh so thanks. I will try to parse it as BlackSlash said. Thanks

Comment: Finally I needed both soultions :D  BlackSlash one and YCF_L. Thanks again

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can solve your problem in inverse mode :

```
public String getResult(String text) {

    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(\\{.*)\\}");
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(text);
    if (matcher.find()) {
        return matcher.group(1);
    } else {
        return null;
    }
}

public static void main(String args[]) {
    Mcve mcve = new Mcve();
    String text = "{HHH { AAAA } fS } SFS}";

    while ((text = mcve.getResult(text)) != null) {
        System.out.println(text);
    }
}
```

**Output**

```
{HHH { AAAA } fS } SFS
{HHH { AAAA } fS 
{HHH { AAAA
```

---

The idea is to get the first result then send this result to the same method until the method return `null` for example :

- Send this String `{HHH { AAAA } fS } SFS}` receive `{HHH { AAAA } fS } SFS`
- Send the result of the previous Iteration `{HHH { AAAA } fS } SFS` receive `{HHH { AAAA } fS`
- Send the result of the previous Iteration `{HHH { AAAA } fS` receive `{HHH { AAAA`
- Send the result of the previous Iteration `{HHH { AAAA` receive `null` now **STOP**

Comment: Wowow! Thanks a lot! Thats what i wanted ! You made my day :D